# two notation: semi-metric and pseudometric

Tags: general-topology, notation, metric-spaces, definition

There are two notations: semi-metric and pseudometric make me unclear. Are they the same thing, or they are different?

Thanks ahead.

Comment: I've seen different uses of these terms.

Comment: @Michael: Use of *pseudometric* is pretty consistent: it would be a metric if it separated points. Use of *semimetric* is less consistent, but the sense that I consider correct is a function that fails to be a metric only because it may not satisfy the triangle inequality.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is some inconsistency in the literature, but most often:

A metric space is a set $S$ with a function $d:S\times S\to \mathbb R$ such that

$d(x,y)\ge 0$

$d(x,x)=0$

$d(x,y)=0\implies x=y$ (separation)

$d(x,y)=d(y,x)$ (symmetry)

$d(x,z)\le d(x,y)+d(y,z)$ (triangle inequality).

A *quasi metric space* satisfies the above except (possibly) for symmetry.

A *pseudo metric space* satisfies the above except (possibly) for separation.

A *semi metric space* often means a space satisfying the above except (possibly) for the triangle inequality. At times though, it also refers to a pseudo metric space, but sometimes it also refers to quasi metric space.

*Generalized metric space* or *Lawvere space* satisfies the above except (possibly) for separation and symmetry.

It is also possible to drop the $d(x,x)=0$ requirement, such things are called *partial metric spaces* and come in both pseudo/semi and quasi variants.

In relation to normed and semi-normed spaces, where the terminology is standard, defining $d(x,y)=\|x-y\|$ associated with a normed spaces a metric space and with a semi-normed space a metric space where $d(x,y)=0\implies x=y$ may fail. This could be seen as support for calling such spaces semi-metric spaces.

Comment: Some people also allow for pseudometric spaces in which the range of the pseudometric is $\mathbb{R}\cup\{+\infty\}$.

Comment: Right. And it should also be noted that it is becoming more and more popular to allows the domain to include $\infty $ for metric spaces as well.

Comment: In my experience the primary sense of *semimetric* is a function that satisfies all of the requirements to be a metric except the triangle inequality.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I reworded the part on semi metric to reflect your comment. Thanks!

Comment: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 2):

I think that

A semi-metric satisfies everything (in the definition of a metric) but not the triangle inequality.

A pseudo-metric satisfies everything except that it can have $d(x,y)=0$ for $x\ne y$. (It still must have $d(x,x)=0$.)