# What is a motivation or geometric intuition of constructing a metric on a product space as an infinite sum?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, proof-explanation, descriptive-set-theory, product-space

In this [notes](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~solomon/notes/desc2.pdf), the author stated the following lemma.

> **Lemma $3.1$** Let $X_0,X_1,...$ be a countable sequence of Polish spaces. Then the product space $\prod X_n$ is also a Polish space.

For all $n\in\mathbb{N},$ let $d_n$ be a complete metric on $X_n$ and assume that $d_n(x,y)<1$ for all $x,y\in X_n.$
To show that the product space $\prod X_n$ is completely metrizable, the author defined the following metric on $\prod X_n$ given by 
$$\hat{d}(f,g) =\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} d_n(f(n),g(n))$$
where $f,g\in\prod X_n.$

> **Question:** What is a motivation or geometric intuition of the metric $\hat{d}?$ 
>   Also, how do we know that the metric $\hat{d}$ is a complete metric on $\prod X_n$ intuitively?

When I tried to prove the lemma myself, I did not think of the metric $\hat{d}.$
Of course, once I know that I have to consider $\hat{d},$ what remains to do is verification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a  geometrically motivated construction; e.g., if you tried to use this metric on a product like $\mathbb{R}^3$, you'd find it does not have  geometrically appealing features. The idea is algebraic, we use addition of "pseudometrics" to separate the points of the product space.

Each individual metric $d_n$ can be considered as  a *pseudometric* on the product space, via
$$
\rho_n(f, g) = d_n(f(n), g(n)) 
$$
A *pseudometric* is different from a metric in that it is allowed to be zero when $f, g$ are not equal. So now we have a bunch of pseudometrics $\{\rho_n\}$ and want to create a metric $\rho$ from them. The issue is how to make sure that $\rho(f,g)>0$ when $f, g$ are different.

If $f\ne g$ then there exists some index $n$ such that $f(n)\ne g(n)$. So we have a pseudometric $\rho_n$ such that $\rho_n(f, g)>0$. Question is, what formula should we use to create $\rho$ from $\rho_n$, so that

1. If at least one $\rho_n$ is positive, then $\rho$ is positive
2. Triangle inequality holds for $\rho$, as it holds for $\rho_n$.
3. If each $d_n$ is complete, $\rho$ is complete.
4. The metric $\rho$ induces the product topology

For example, $\rho = \sup_n \rho_n$ works for (1-3) but fails (4); the topology it induces (uniform convergence) is stronger than the product topology (componentwise convergence).

We could use a weighted supremum: $\rho = \sup_n c_n\rho_n$ where $c_n>0$ and $c_n\to 0$ (suggested by Daniel Fischer). Then all (1-4) hold. The fact that $c_n\to 0$ makes $\rho$ small when sufficiently many of the components $\rho_n$ are small, not necessarily all of them.

Or, we could use a sum instead of supremum. $\sum_n \rho_n$ doesn't work since it need not converge. So pick a convergent series $\sum c_n$ with positive terms, and let $\rho = \sum_n c_n \rho_n$. Again, properties (1) and (2) are easy to check. And now (3) is easier to prove. Indeed, a sequence $f_k$ being Cauchy with respect to $\rho$ implies that for every $n$, the  $n$-th component sequence $\{f_k(n)\}$ is Cauchy with respect to the corresponding $d_n$, and thus converges. So we have a coordinate-wise limit $f_k\to f$. Unlike the construction with supremum, coordinate-wise convergence implies convergence in the metric $\rho = \sum_n c_n \rho_n$. Indeed, for any $\epsilon>0$ there is $N$ such that $\sum_{n>N} c_n<\epsilon/2$, so the tail  of the sequence is negligible. And for large enough $k$ we will have $\rho_n(f_k, f)<\epsilon/(2N)$, $n=1,\dots, N$. Combine the two to get $\rho(f_k, f)<\epsilon$.

#### Observations

- Most of this is not really about products; this is just a construction of a metric from countably many bounded pseudometrics. (Except for property 4 which is indeed specific to products.)
- There is nothing special about $1/2^{n}$, except it happens to be the world's favorite convergent series.  Any convergent series with positive terms could be used.

Comment: Maybe it's worth noting that the term semimetric is also used for [a different thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_%28mathematics%29#Semimetrics), and what is here called semi-metric is also called pseudometric. These two notions should not be confused. Among analysts, it is common to use the name semimetric (or semi-metric) in the sense of this answer, because these things have the same relation to metrics as seminorms have to norms.

Comment: Among topologists, the other meaning of semimetric [seems common](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/333709/two-notation-semi-metric-and-pesudometric#comment720449_333709). And another common construction to obtain a metric that induces the product topology on a countable product of metric spaces is $$d(x,y) = \max \{ c_n \rho_n(x,y) : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$$ where $(c_n)$ is a sequence of strictly positive numbers converging to $0$.

Comment: Good points; I would normally use "pseudometric" myself but was thinking of seminorms when writing this.