# Is the product of metric and semi-metric functions a semi metric?

Tags: metric-spaces, products

I have a function - $B_{DGC}(x,y) = K_{(x,y)} \times e^{-(\frac{(I_x - I_y)^2}{2\sigma^2})}\times \frac{1}{d(x,y)} \times \frac{1}{\delta(x,y)_{DGC}}$. The components $K_{(x,y)}$ and $\frac{1}{\delta(x,y)_{DGC}}$ are semi metric, $\frac{1}{d(x,y)}$ is metric and $e^{-(\frac{(I_x - I_y)^2}{2\sigma^2})}$ is quasi metric. Is $B_{DGC}(x,y)$ a semi metric?

Comment: What means " semi- metric" ?

Comment: I don't know what a semi-metric is either, but the product of two metrics is not necessarily a metric, so ... probably not?

Comment: The title and body of the question don’t match.

Comment: From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space#Generalizations_of_metric_spaces): “There are also numerous ways of relaxing the axioms for a metric, giving rise to various notions of generalized metric spaces. These generalizations can also be combined. The terminology used to describe them is not completely standardized. Most notably, in functional analysis pseudometrics often come from seminorms on vector spaces, and so it is natural to call them ‘semimetrics’. This conflicts with the use of the term in topology.” So you should define your terms.

Comment: As mentioned in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/333723/1301381) - "A semi metric space often means a space satisfying the above except (possibly) for the triangle inequality. At times though, it also refers to a pseudo metric space, but sometimes it also refers to quasi metric space.", My question is - if there is a semi metric function (that does not satisfy triangle inequality) and a metric function (that does satisfy triangle inequality), can we prove that their product is a semi metric (the product of the functions does not satisfy triangle inequality)?